# How can I prevent laravel from firing events inside of tests?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I've just written a laravel [Observer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#observers). It is attached to a `Company` model as I want to know the users that created a company. I have a large suite of other tests which use factories to setup companies. These tests now fail because the observer needs a user but no user is logged in when the factory is called.

CompanyObserver.php

```
class CompanyObserver {
    function created(Company $company) {
        info('USER ' . Auth::user()->id . ' created the new company ' . $company->id . '.';
    }
}
```

OldTests.php

```
Class OldTests {
    function testSomething() {
        // Now fails because observer is triggered but no use is logged in.
        $company = factory(Company::class)->create();

        // Random request
        $this->post('getCompany/' . $company->id)->assertStatus(200);
    }
}
```

How can I handle having a new observer that require a user to be logged in for my old tests? Do I have to go and change all my old tests?

Comment: You could change the observer to do an `Auth::check` before attempting to use it, or you can login in your old tests. Not sure if there is a way to disable events. I guess it depends how you're firing them, maybe you can mock something to avoid really firing.

Comment: At the beginning of your test call `Event::fake();` more info on event fake in [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mocking#event-fake)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Laravel 8, this should work.

```
$company = Company::withoutEvents(function () {
        return Company::factory()->create();
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

At the beginning of your test call `Event::fake();`

This will fake all the events in the test.
You can the use asserting functions on the faked `Event` to complete your tests and see the events were fired.

You can fake the event for a specific scope like so

```php
$company = Event::fakeFor(function () {
    $company = factory(Company::class)->create();

    Event::assertDispatched(CompanyCreated::class);

    return $company;
});
//use $company for the rest of the test
```

More info on faking the events in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mocking#event-fake)

Comment: So this would mean for a very large chunk of my feature tests my events would be faked. I know I can fake a specific event. Is it possible to turn on event faker and then turn it off after my factories have run? I'd still like them to run during my production code execution.